# How do you get the Mac-address of a Networking Card in Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, mac-address

I'm running XP SP2 and need to get the MAC address of the card running on this machine.

Where do I get that from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter following from command prompt:

```
ipconfig /all
```

This will list all your network cards, they state, and info incl. IP, MAC, and others.

Comment: Yep, it was listed under 'Physical Address'. Thanks.

Comment: Um, I believe that should be `ipconfig`, eh?

Comment: Why not actually try it before you comment? :) There has never been an "ifconfig" in Windows.

Comment: Right, post updated.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the mac address type: 
 getmac

Comment: +1 That's works great also. Thanks.

Comment: No problem glad to help.

Comment: Doesn't work here.  Must get installed with some other package?

Comment: @gbarry What OS are you running?

Comment: sudo apt-get install arp-scan
sudo arp-scan 192.168.1.0/24 

if using a flavor of Linux.

Comment: @mikedopp Check tags much?